# missing tooltips in #develop

Tags: code-completion, sharpdevelop

Since I reinstalled #develop to another machine I experience a quite annoying issue:

When typing method calls etc. for standard-libraries (System.Net.Sockets e.g.) I don't get the full "tool-tips" anymore.

```
TCPClient foo = new TCPClient(
```

At this point I still get the "4 overloads available" and can cycle through them

```
public TCPClient(string hostname, int port) //e.g.
```

What I am NOT getting is the explainatory text
"creates an new instance of TCP-Client, hostname: the name of the host system, port: the port number"

So far I went through all options, but didn't find anything that seemed related to my issue.
Any idea which option to (un-)tick or what else to do?

Answer (score 0):

On your new machine it is likely you are missing an extra piece of software that installs the XML documentation.

The XML documentation should be included in the .NET SDK which is a part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279). There is also XML documentation for [.NET 4.5.1 in the developer pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772).

I would check if you have the .NET 4.5 SDK installed on your machine in Programs and Features. I would also check if the .xml files exist next to the assemblies you are referencing. You can see the file location of the assembly reference in the Projects window. The TCPClient is in System.dll. On my machine project this reference exists in the directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
```

This directory includes the System.xml file which SharpDevelop will use when showing code completion for the TCPClient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check ASAP

Comment: And indeed that is what I am missing. Would've taken me ages to figure that out. I assumed the XML-documentation came with the framework itself. Now it is time to wait for an IT-drone to arrive and fix this.